# How can i use DatagridTextColumn.ElementStyle to Make DatagridTextColumn readonly?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, datagridtextcolumn

can i use elementStyle to bind DatagridTextColumn IsReadOnly to a Property inside a ViewModel(here IsReadOnlyProperty)?
something like this:

```
  <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
          <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsReadOnlyProperty}"/>
      </Style>
  </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
  <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
               <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsReadOnlyProperty}" />
        </Style>
  </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```

Comment: Have you tried [DataGridTextColumn.IsReadOnly Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.isreadonly.aspx)?

Comment: sure i did!!it dosen't get bind!!

Comment: IsReadOnlyProperty isn't inside datagrid Itemsource,it's placed in a ViewModel.

Comment: @raha: Your ItemsSource should be collection of view models though, so in which context is that view model accessible?

Comment: but it works!!the view model is in window context!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.IsReadOnlyProperty}" />
```

When you create DataGrid, you set its DataContext by assigning ItemsSource. This limits ALL controls inside DataGrid to only use objects from their parent DataContext, so if you want to bind to a property from outside of this DataContext, you have to explicitly declare that you want to change your scope.